# Devise Parameter Sanitizer not working with Cucumber / Capybara / Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to upgrade from rails 4.0 to 4.1

All of my sign_in tests have suddenly failed with the following error:

```
undefined method `visit' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007fe83cf0b898> (NoMethodError)
```

Has anyone encountered this error? Any idea how to fix it?
It looks like the scope of the step_definitions is being pointed at the wrong Object, but I've no idea how to point it at something sensible.

The steps are all calling something like this method:

```
def sign_in_as_client
  visit 'users/sign_in'
  fill_in "user_login", :with => @client_params[:email]
  fill_in "Password", :with => @client_params[:password]
  click_button "Sign in" rescue nil
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropped devise back to v3.5.9 and that seemed to make it go away. 
Happy to hear advice on what to do with devise 4+.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `sign_in` (and other) methods to within the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` class resolved this issue for me:

Before (failing):

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  ...
end

def sign_in(email='scott.miller@test.com')
  visit "/en/users/sign_in"
  ...
end
```

After (working):

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  ...

  def sign_in(email='scott.miller@test.com')
    visit "/en/users/sign_in"
    ...
  end
end
```